Error when launching Docker Compose with ActiveMQ Artemis service and dependent applications
The ActiveMQ Artemis service starts perfectly, as does the container for quarkus-camel-archetype-soap. However, when trying to launch the next application, app-quarkus-api, it fails with the error below. This project works fine when I run it directly on my machine using the terminal with mvn quarkus:dev, without any errors. But when I try to launch it with Docker Compose on my local machine, I encounter an error, and I'm not sure why. My suspicion is that it might be related to the network, where it can't resolve tcp://artemis:61616, or maybe something else. The code seems to work since it connects and runs fine when not using Docker, and both projects use the same Dockerfile. Could Artemis have issues with this type of connection?
networks:
  red_artemis_mq:
    driver: bridge
 
services:
  artemis:
    image: apache/activemq-artemis:2.38.0
    container_name: artemis-broker
    environment: 
      - ARTEMIS_PERF_JOURNAL=AUTO
    ports:
      - "8161:8161"   # Web Console
      - "61616:61616" # CORE,MQTT,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE  Port
      - "5672:5672"   # AMQP Port 
    volumes:
      - artemis-data:/var/lib/artemis-instance
      - ./artemis-users.properties:/var/lib/artemis-instance/etc/artemis-users.properties
      - ./artemis-roles.properties:/var/lib/artemis-instance/etc/artemis-roles.properties
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - red_artemis_mq
      
  quarkus-camel-archetype-soap:
    build:
      context: ./quarkus-camel-archetype-soap
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.jvm
    container_name: quarkus-camel-archetype-soap
    ports:
      - "8182:8182"   
    networks:
      - red_artemis_mq
    depends_on:
      - artemis
      
  app-quarkus-api:
    build:
      context: ./app-quarkus-api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.jvm
    container_name: app-quarkus-api
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"  
    environment:
      - AMQ_ARTEMIS_URL=tcp://artemis:61616
      - AMQ_ARTEMIS_USERNAME=artemis
      - AMQ_ARTEMIS_PASSWORD=artemis 
    networks:
      - red_artemis_mq
    depends_on:
      - artemis

volumes:
  artemis-data:
    driver: local

DockerFile de cada aplicacion
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-17:1.18

ENV LANGUAGE='en_US:en'

# We make four distinct layers so if there are application changes the library layers can be re-used
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/lib/ /deployments/lib/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/*.jar /deployments/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/app/ /deployments/app/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/quarkus/ /deployments/quarkus/

EXPOSE 8080
USER 185
ENV JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Dquarkus.log.level=TRACE"
ENV JAVA_APP_JAR="/deployments/quarkus-run.jar"

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/jboss/container/java/run/run-java.sh" ]

2024-11-27 01:12:07 2024-11-27 04:12:07,960 DEBUG [io.quarkus.arc.impl] (main) ArC DI container shut down
2024-11-27 01:12:07 
2024-11-27 01:12:07 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doRun(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:62)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.main(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:33)
2024-11-27 01:12:07 Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     ... 6 more
2024-11-27 01:12:07 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     ... 15 more
2024-11-27 01:12:07 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.nio.file.Path.resolve(String)" because the return value of "io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentInfo.getTempPath()" is null
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder.bootServletContainer(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:556)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.UndertowBuildStep$build767851419.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.UndertowBuildStep$build767851419.deploy(Unknown Source)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     ... 16 more
2024-11-27 01:12:07 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.nio.file.Path.resolve(String)" because the return value of "io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentInfo.getTempPath()" is null
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:253)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder.bootServletContainer(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:545)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     ... 18 more
2024-11-27 01:12:07 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.nio.file.Path.resolve(String)" because the return value of "io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentInfo.getTempPath()" is null
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.setupMultipart(ManagedServlet.java:101)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.<init>(ManagedServlet.java:73)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlets.addServlet(ManagedServlets.java:46)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.createServletsAndFilters(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:266)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.access$100(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:121)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:195)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$9$1.call(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:604)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:251)
2024-11-27 01:12:07     ... 19 more

